# Is there an alloy of iridium/tungsten or iridium / molybdenum?

Tags: metals

I searched everywhere, but just couldn't find any iridium/tungsten or iridium / molybdenum alloy. What can be their properties  if there any.

Comment: Looking very hard cannot have included a web search.

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: I found something. I googled "tunsten iridium alloy". There doesn't seem to be much for "iridium molybdenum alloy".

Comment: The ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database has Ir-Mo (taken from BInary Alloy Phase Diagrams, 2nd edition) - it shows 5 intermetallic phases. From the same handbook one finds several Ir-W intermetallics, with several ordered sub-phases at lower temperatures of the main IrW phase. Check the reference center of your library for the handbook.